# Custom ListAdapter in popup menu like AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, popupmenu

I have to show a list of items, in a customized row, just like PopupMenu http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu
But the problem is i didn't get how to use Custom Adapter with PopupMenu same as we use it in AlertDialogs and ListView.
have anybody worked around it, please guide me.

Comment: you dont set Adapter to PopupMenu, you set it to AdapterView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here i added the sample code for you. Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks, Please let me know.

**spinnerpopup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <com.stackoverflow.SpinnerContext
      android:id="@+id/spinnerContext"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="7dp"></com.stackoverflow.SpinnerContext>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SpinnerSample.java** Activity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.stackoverflow.SpinnerContext;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class SpinnerSample extends Activity {
     static SpinnerContext spinnerContext;
     static List<String> listSubContext = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinnerpopup);
    addItemsOnContext();        
    }

    public void addItemsOnContext() {
        spinnerContext = (SpinnerContext) findViewById(R.id.spinnerContext);
        List<String> listContext = new ArrayList<String>();
        listContext.add("Units");
        listContext.add("Temperature");
        listContext.add("Mass");
        listContext.add("Length");
        listContext.add("Speed");
        listContext.add("Time");
        listContext.add("Area");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listContext);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        spinnerContext.setAdapter(dataAdapter);         
        spinnerContext.setOnItemSelectedEvenIfUnchangedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SpinnerSample.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_sub_context);
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                ListView list = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listSubContext);
                dialog.setTitle("Context for Call");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.show();
                onStop();
                listSubContext.clear();  
                if(spinnerContext.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Temperature"){
                    listSubContext.add("Celsius");
                    listSubContext.add("Fahrenheit");
                }else if(spinnerContext.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Mass"){
                    listSubContext.add("Metric Ton");
                    listSubContext.add("Kilogram");
                    listSubContext.add("Gram");
                    listSubContext.add("Milligram");
                    listSubContext.add("Pound");
                    listSubContext.add("Ounce");
                }else if(spinnerContext.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Length"){
                    listSubContext.add("Kilometer");
                    listSubContext.add("Meter");
                    listSubContext.add("Centimeter");
                    listSubContext.add("Millimeter");
                    listSubContext.add("Mile");
                    listSubContext.add("Yard");
                    listSubContext.add("Foot");
                    listSubContext.add("Inch");
                }else if(spinnerContext.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Speed"){
                    listSubContext.add("Miles/Hour");
                    listSubContext.add("Feet/Sec");
                    listSubContext.add("Meters/Sec");
                    listSubContext.add("Km/Hour");
                    listSubContext.add("Knot");
                }else if(spinnerContext.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Time"){
                    listSubContext.add("Nanosecond");
                    listSubContext.add("Microsecond");
                    listSubContext.add("Meters/Sec");
                    listSubContext.add("Km/Hour");
                    listSubContext.add("Knot");
                }else if(spinnerContext.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Area"){
                    listSubContext.add("Square km");
                    listSubContext.add("Square meter");
                    listSubContext.add("Square mile");
                    listSubContext.add("Hectare");
                    listSubContext.add("Acre");
                    listSubContext.add("Square yard");
                    listSubContext.add("Square foot");
                }else if(spinnerContext.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Units"){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (SpinnerSample.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listSubContext);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);               
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
                        view.setSelected(true);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }      
        });
    }
}
```

**SpinnerContext.java** extends spinner

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class SpinnerContext extends Spinner {
    OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    public SpinnerContext(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        super.setSelection(position);
        if (listener != null)
        listener.onItemSelected(null, null, position, 0);
    }

    public void setOnItemSelectedEvenIfUnchangedListener(
        OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }   
}
```